# How to delete the attendance check function in Google invitation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to implement a just notification Google calendar invitation. Currently I'm using Ruby to send a conventional Google Calendar invitation in the service, and it has "yes or no" attendance check button. In order not to attend the meeting, our service customer should indicate their unavailability via the website, but it seems they just clicked no there.

The below is my current code and I think I have to add one or two lines in this code but I'm now sure what that is.

```
        begin
          event = {
            'summary' => 'Ringle Class',
            'description' => 'Ringle Class Notification. Case:' + lesson.course.title,
            'start' => {
              'dateTime' => lesson.start_time.to_datetime
            },
            'end' => {
              'dateTime' => (lesson.start_time + 1.hour ).to_datetime
            },
            'attendees' => [
            {'email' => lesson.student.email},{'email' => 'xx@xx.com'} 
            ],
          }
          results = GOOGLE_CAL_CLIENT.execute!(
          :api_method => GOOGLE_CAL_API.events.insert,
          :parameters => {
            :calendarId => GOOGLE_CAL_ID,
            'sendNotifications' => true,
            'locked' => true,
            },
          :body_object => event)
          lesson.ginv_student = true
          lesson.save 
          $google_invi_log.debug "Sent to the student#{lesson.id}"
        rescue
          $google_invi_log.debug "Not sent to the student #{lesson.id}"          
        end
```

Please share with me any idea you have (:!!

Best

Comment: The attendees has a response status http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FCalendarV3%2FEventAttendee%3Aresponse_status

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. But what I want to do is not to allow user to click yes or no in my invitation email. The above link looks like I'll get the info whether the user will join or not. Can you provide a bit more info how to delete "attendance check part" ? (:! Thanks so much!

Comment: I have not extensively used this API but I think this can help. Setting the user role to freeBusyReader or reader might help http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FCalendarV3%2FEvents%3Aaccess_role